# Ubuntu terminal commands using SCSI tool induce disk failure

Tags: testing, iscsi, scsi

I have written a code to do read & write(random file) pulling a hard disk performance.But,I also want to check when there is a disk failure.So,I am trying to induce disk failure using **SCSI** tool.But,I am unable to get any insights for it.Can anybody direct me to do the same.

Comment: Which tool are you trying to use? And what kind of disk failure do you want to induce?

Comment: I want to use SCSI tool.To create a bad sector and failed hard disk.Inject the hard disk device.Using ubuntu terminal commands.(i.e., crontab)

Comment: I doubt that this is possible. I have never seen any software tool that can, on command, create a bad sector. You may want to talk to disk vendors, as they may have tools for simulating such behavior.

Comment: Ok..Thank You @vidarlo for your support.Please keep on touch.